# Error on starting weblogic server in jdeveloper

Tags: jvm, weblogic

Can anyone please help me to resolve this error?

Below is the weblogic server log...

I'm using Jdk 7, and Java Developer for ADF

```
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Unrecognized option: -jrockit
Process exited.


--Weblogic server log-------



    *** Using HTTP port 7101 ***
    *** Using SSL port 7102 ***
    C:\Users\inatar\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system11.1.2.4.39.64.36.1\DefaultDomain\bin\startWebLogic.cmd
    [waiting for the server to complete its initialization...]
    .
    .
    JAVA Memory arguments: -Xms256m -Xmx512m
    .
    WLS Start Mode=Development
    .
    CLASSPATH=C:\Oracle\Middleware\oracle_common\modules\oracle.jdbc_11.1.1\ojdbc6dms.jar;C:\Oracle\Middl
    eware\patch_wls1035\profiles\default\sys_manifest_classpath\weblogic_patch.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\p
atch_jdev1112\profiles\default\sys_manifest_classpath\weblogic_patch.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\Java\jdk1.7.0_67
\lib\tools.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\wlserver_10.3\server\lib\weblogic_sp.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\wls
erver_10.3\server\lib\weblogic.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\modules\features\weblogic.server.modules_10.3
.5.0.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\wlserver_10.3\server\lib\webservices.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\modules\o
rg.apache.ant_1.7.1/lib/ant-all.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\modules\net.sf.antcontrib_1.1.0.0_1-
0b2/lib/ant-
contrib.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\oracle_common\modules\oracle.jrf_11.1.1\jrf.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware
\wlserver_10.3\common\derby\lib\derbyclient.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\wlserver_10.3\server\lib\xqrl.jar
    .
    PATH=C:\Oracle\Middleware\patch_wls1035\profiles\default\native;C:\Oracle\Middleware\patch_jdev1112\p
rofiles\default\native;C:\Oracle\Middleware\wlserver_10.3\server\native\win\32;C:\Oracle\Middleware\w
lserver_10.3\server\bin;C:\Oracle\Middleware\modules\org.apache.ant_1.7.1\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\Java\jdk1.7
.0_67\jre\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\bin;E:\DB\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin;;c:\Program 
Files\RSA SecurID Token Common;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS 
Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell
\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program 
Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program 
Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\bin;C:\Oracle\Middleware\wlserver_10.3\server\native\win\32\oci920_8
    .
    ***************************************************
    *  To start WebLogic Server, use a username and   *
    *  password assigned to an admin-level user.  For *
    *  server administration, use the WebLogic Server *
    *  console at http:\\hostname:port\console        *
    ***************************************************
    starting weblogic with Java version:
    Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
    Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
    Unrecognized option: -jrockit
    Starting WLS with line:
    C:\PROGRA~1\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\bin\java -jrockit   -Xms256m -Xmx512m -Dweblogic.Name=DefaultServer 
    -Djava.security.policy=C:\Oracle\Middleware\wlserver_10.3\server\lib\weblogic.policy -
    Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\Users\inatar\AppData\Local\Temp\trustStore8547229804589400188.jks -
    Doracle.jdeveloper.adrs=true -Dweblogic.nodemanager.ServiceEnabled=true  -Xverify:none  -da -
    Dplatform.home=C:\Oracle\Middleware\wlserver_10.3 -
    Dwls.home=C:\Oracle\Middleware\wlserver_10.3\server -
    Dweblogic.home=C:\Oracle\Middleware\wlserver_10.3\server  -Djps.app.credential.overwrite.allowed=true 
    -Dcommon.components.home=C:\Oracle\Middleware\oracle_common -Djrf.version=11.1.1 -
    Dorg.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger -
    Ddomain.home=C:\Users\inatar\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system11.1.2.4.39.64.36.1\DefaultDomain -
        Djrockit.optfile=C:\Oracle\Middleware\oracle_common\modules\oracle.jrf_11.1.1\jrocket_optfile.txt -
    Doracle.server.config.dir=C:\Users\inatar\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system11.1.2.4.39.64.36.1\Defaul
tDomain\config\fmwconfig\servers\DefaultServer -
    Doracle.domain.config.dir=C:\Users\inatar\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system11.1.2.4.39.64.36.1\Defaul
tDomain\config\fmwconfig  -
    Digf.arisidbeans.carmlloc=C:\Users\inatar\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system11.1.2.4.39.64.36.1\Defaul
tDomain\config\fmwconfig\carml  -
Digf.arisidstack.home=C:\Users\inatar\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system11.1.2.4.39.64.36.1\DefaultDom
ain\config\fmwconfig\arisidprovider -
    Doracle.security.jps.config=C:\Users\inatar\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system11.1.2.4.39.64.36.1\Defa
ultDomain\config\fmwconfig\jps-config.xml -
    Doracle.deployed.app.dir=C:\Users\inatar\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system11.1.2.4.39.64.36.1\Default
Domain\servers\DefaultServer\tmp\_WL_user -Doracle.deployed.app.ext=\- -
    Dweblogic.alternateTypesDirectory=C:\Oracle\Middleware\oracle_common\modules\oracle.ossoiap_11.1.1,C:
\Oracle\Middleware\oracle_common\modules\oracle.oamprovider_11.1.1 -
Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=oracle.mds.net.protocol  -Dweblogic.jdbc.remoteEnabled=false -
    Dwsm.repository.path=C:\Users\inatar\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system11.1.2.4.39.64.36.1\DefaultDoma
in\oracle\store\gmds   -Dweblogic.management.discover=true  -Dwlw.iterativeDev= -    Dwlw.testConsole= -
Dwlw.logErrorsToConsole= -
    Dweblogic.ext.dirs=C:\Oracle\Middleware\patch_wls1035\profiles\default\sysext_manifest_classpath;C:\O
racle\Middleware\patch_jdev1112\profiles\default\sysext_manifest_classpath  weblogic.Server
    Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
    Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
    Unrecognized option: -jrockit
    Process exited.
```

Answer (score 0):

`Unrecognized option: -jrockit Process exited.` is the critical error. `-jrockit` is not an option available to the standard java jdk.

e.g. `C:\PROGRA~1\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\bin\java -jrockit` is the issue

Your `JAVA_VENDOR` is being set incorrectly in your `setDomainEnv.cmd` or `startWebLogic.cmd` script. It's being set to `Oracle` but should be set to `Sun`. You either need to figure out how that environment variable is being set incorrectly or manually fix one of the two .cmd files.

Answer (score 0):

My last post was bad!
Here is the unwrapped set of lines I added:
  echo "==> Force JAVA_VM to use -server:"
  JAVA_VM=-server
  export JAVA_VM
  echo "."
  echo "."
  echo "JAVA Machine: ${JAVA_VM}"

Answer (score -2):

THIS ISSUE IS RESOLVED FOR ME. I JUST WANTED TO POST THE SOLUTION SOMEWHERE...
I was working through exercise 1 on the NoSQL intro: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/bigdata/articles/intro-to-oracle-nosql-db-hol-1937059.pdf

I tried to deploy the Movieplex application to JDeveloper's internal weblogic server but kept getting hit with a -jrockit VM not found. This was difficult for me to get fixed because: 1 - I am not a heavy java programmer, and 2 - I apparently do not read very well. As for point 1, JRockit is an optimized special JAVA VM that some folks use. You can look that up oon line I guess, but it looks like we do not need it for this tutorial. As for point 2, I spent hours (I ashamedly admit) trying to figure out what .sh scripts were being run to start the Weblogic server running. I did all sorts of find commands, hunted through the binaries and folders underneath the Middleware folders. In the end, all I has to do was read the output log carefully, the script for me is: /home/oracle/.jdeveloper/system11.1.1.6.38.61.92/DefaultDomain/bin/startWebLogic.sh.

I edited the script REPLACING line 129 with below:

echo "==> Force JAVA_VM to use -server:"
JAVA_VM=-server
export JAVA_VM

echo "."

echo "."

echo "JAVA Machine: ${JAVA_VM}"

NOTE: there is another shell script that may be involved, /home/oracle/.jdeveloper/system11.1.1.6.38.61.92/Default/init-info/Domain